# I have written a query (SQL) in R to get some data from a database. I'd like to pass the date assigned by a subroutine in R instead of hard coding it

Tags: mysql, r, function

```
DATA=dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT 
                  A, 
                  B as 'Ba',
                  C  as 'Ca',  
                  D as 'Da',
                  date as 'Date'
                  from database where date>='2000-01-01' and date<='2001-01-01' ")
```

I'd like to replace the '2000-01-01' and '2001-01-01' by "date1 and date2", both provided in a function or subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that would be

```
f <- function(date1, date2) 
  dbGetQuery(conn, paste0("SELECT A, B as 'Ba', C as 'Ca', D as 'Da', date as 'Date' from database where date>='", date1, "' and date<='", date2, "' "))
```

Check out `?paste` for the documentation.